# Using velocity.js UI pack animations with velocity-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, velocity.js

How do I use velocity.js UI pack effects in my react app? 
With the following code the`fadeOut` animation is working, but `slideRightIn` is not.

```
import { VelocityTransitionGroup } from 'velocity-react';
import 'velocity-animate/velocity.ui';


class ShowForm extends React.Component {
  [...]
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <VelocityTransitionGroup enter={{animation: "slideRightIn"}} leave={{animation: "fadeOut"}} duration="1">
         {this.getActiveStep()}
       </VelocityTransitionGroup>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The error in console is `Velocity: First argument (slideRightIn) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect`

Comment: I'm having problem with getting `velocity-react` and `velocity-animate` working on my project (webpack-based). I keep getting `windows is undefined` or `stagger: undefined.stateduration` errors. I'm not sure where to import or require these module apart from the component JSX where I am going to consume them. Where did you do that?

Comment: Docs say you need to import the libs at the root component of your app. Concerning your errors, I never encountered them, so cannot help with that.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason for this roblem was that animation name is `transition.slideRightIn`, not just `slideRightIn`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days...very frustrating...velocity 1.5...I've been upgrading to react 16.2.  The following component code stopped working with the above mentioned error...the component is just a span wrapped in a

...Inside velocity the Velocity.Redirects[propertiesMap] only had fadeIn,fadeOut etc...not transition.xxx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class StatusMessage extends React.Component {...

  _animateText(text) {
        var textNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textSpan),
        that = this;
    Velocity(textNode, "transition.shrinkIn", {
        duration: 150,
        delay: 50,
        begin: function() {
            that.setState({
                text: text
            });
            that.animating = true;
        },
        complete: function() {
            that.animating = false;
            that.forceUpdate();
        }
    });
}
}
```

To fix it I added one import statement to my root App component...

```
import 'velocity-animate/velocity.ui';
class App extends React.Component { ...
```

I hope this helps someone else too.
Cheers!